# SDL Not Being Found For MinGW

Tags: c, compiler-errors, sdl, mingw32

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I've followed the tutorial here: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/mingw/index.php

I cannot get g++ to compile. I receive the following error:

```
testgame.c:1:21: fatal error: SDL/SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include "SDL/SDL.h"
```

Here is the code in the file:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;    
}
```

Directories:

`C:\MinGW\include\` - This is where I placed the SDL folder with *.h files

`C:\MinGW\lib\` - This is where I placed all the lib files for SDL

I've also placed the SDL.dll in my file/executable directory.

I'm using the following to compile:

```
g++ -o testgame.exe testgame.c -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL
```

I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. I've searched all over and nothing has worked so far. Please help!

Thanks,
Travis

Update:

Changing the include statement to:

```
#include "C:/MinGW/include/SDL/SDL.h"
```

Fixes the initial error but now I receive:

```
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDLmain
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

@cat Suggested the following:

```
g++ -o testgame.exe testgame.c -lmingw32 -L.SDLmain -lSDL
```

However this returned this error:

```
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL
```

@vonaka Suggested:

```
g++ -o testgame.exe testgame.c -lmingw32 -LC:/MinGW/lib/
```

However, this returned multiple errors.

Comment: Try adding a -L. (upper case L dot) before your -lSDLmain

Comment: Note that SDL1 is *old*. You should learn SDL2 instead.

Comment: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php

Comment: @cat I've tried both suggestions and still receive and still receive different errors. I will updated the question with them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've tried SDL2 as well. I switched to SDL1 to try and get it to work.

Comment: @TravisCouture If I were you, I'd switch back to SDL2 and try to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat SDL2 gave the same exact errors. I switched to SDL1 because that's what the tutorial was for. I intend to switch back once I figure this out.

Comment: @vonaka That still returns a long list of errors.

Comment: @vonaka It stilled couldn't find -lSDLmain and -lSDL. It also said skipping incompatible SDL.dll when searching for -lSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to fix this problem. I placed all the relevant SDL and/or SDL2 files into a separate folder in C:\ called mingw_dev_lib. Then I explicitly stated the paths to the lib folder and the include folder inside this new directory with the following:

```
gcc testgame.c -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o testgame.exe
```

The compilation was successful after these steps. It is strange though that it wouldn't compile when trying to access these files and the standard C:\MinGW directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the g++ you used was not the one where you copied the SDL library files. It's possible that another program has installed its own MinGW and set a system path to it (e.g. Perl uses MinGW to compile modules). You can find out with:

```
where g++
```

To resolve this issue you can change the system path (requires re-opening the shell) or rename unused MinGW folders.